# Loading / Preparing jQuery in a modal that is not shown

Tags: jquery, vue.js, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using the [Bootstrap DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) in a project with Vue.JS. This has generally worked fine, but I recently ran into an issue that I've never encountered and that colors me confused.

On page load, there are two DateTime-pickers, that both work. See [this partial screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHhGM.png). However, further down on the page, there are buttons that invoke a new Vue.JS Modal (clicking the button essentially calls `$('#modal-xxx').modal('show');`.

Placing these DateTime-pickers inside of that modal render them not working. The actual styling still loads - but they won't trigger. I'm thinking this is because the JavaScript for these is stuck in between two states;

a) A state where it is called when the modal appears, which, as I understand it, will never work - as a browser only interprets what it needs to upon page load, and then stops.

b) Loading on page-load, which again, presumably won't work, as the elements are not visible at that point.

I've tried working around this to the best of my abilites - but no matter if  the javascript for calling these DateTimePickers is placed in the modal itself - or on the bottom of page - it still renders the elements useless.

I've attached the example codebase below:

```
<div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': updateExampleForm.errors.has('example')}">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Example</label>

    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='input-group date' id='update_example'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" v-model="updateExampleForm.example" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $('#update_example').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
        <span class="help-block" v-show="updateExampleForm.errors.has('example')">
            @{{ updateExampleForm.errors.get('example') }}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone confirm why this won't trigger the expected results (being the form working) - and if so, what would be an alternative way to doing this? If you're able to elaborate on the thinking behind whatever alternative method you come up with - that's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this wound up being to do this in the function that shows the modal:

```
    editExample(example) {
        $('#modal-update-example').modal('show');
        this.$nextTick(function(){
            $('#update_example_1').datetimepicker();
            $('#update_example_2').datetimepicker();
        });
    }
```

This waited until other actions were done, and then instantiated the date-timepicker on the elements.